# Show all ForeignKeys which point to a particular row

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key

How to list all Foreignkeys (table + column + pk-of-that-row) which point to a particular row in a given table.

Example: the table "user" has row with PK '1234'.

I want to see all FKs which point to exactly this user with ID '1234'.

I use PostgreSQL 12.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows all table and column names that reference column `id` in table `data`:

```
SELECT fk.conrelid::regclass AS referencing_table,
       a2.attname AS referencing_column
FROM pg_constraint AS fk
   JOIN pg_constraint AS uk ON fk.conindid = uk.conindid
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(uk.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS ukc(attnum, n)
   JOIN LATERAL unnest(fk.conkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS fkc(attnum, n) USING (n)
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a1 ON ukc.attnum = a1.attnum AND a1.attrelid = uk.conrelid
   JOIN pg_attribute AS a2 ON fkc.attnum = a2.attnum AND a2.attrelid = fk.conrelid
WHERE fk.contype = 'f'
  AND uk.contype IN ('p'::"char", 'u'::"char")
  AND fk.conislocal
  AND uk.conrelid = 'data'::regclass
  AND a1.attname = 'id';
```

Querying those tables for the entries that reference a certain row is left as an exercise to the reader. You won't be able to do it all in a single query.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Did you wrote this statement, or do you have a cheat sheet where this query was already listed?

Comment: I wrote that from scratch, since that is a requirement I never had. I use `psql` and run `\d data` to see what foreign keys point to my table. Good tools spoil you.